# Can i refresh (getText and setText) all Edit Text values in one go ?

Tags: android

I am using Edit Text watcher, to do some calculations.like below,

[image]

And every Edit Text group (A,B,C) is working fine independently and relatively. But relatively worked only if i come from top to bottom. I want to refresh (getText and setText) on every Edit Text onTextChange() method invoked. i can do this using custom method .

But can i do this in one go , like all edit text values of a particular XML get refresh, so each editText onTextChange will be called in TOP-DOWN approach, Because every descendent group is dependent in some context to previous group .

Comment: Create one method and call it on every edittext on text change listener. Where you need to check the values of all edittext is exist or not, and use values if available for calculation.

Comment: Create one onTextChanged method for all of them? Instead of creating a `new TextViewer()` for every single one, implement it in the class you're in and pass it to every text field you have.

Comment: @G_V hey , i am getting data from database and allow user input also. So when database values set on each edit text , common onTextChanged() method called and set default value 0 to each Edittext.

Answer (score 0):

This is doable, you just must have an algorithm. But yes, it is possible, and not too challenging...

As a hint, EditText.onTextChanged() methods inside of the each listener will need access its other 5 EditText siblings/neighbors. (A-C rows and 1-2 columns, respectively). 
All 6 onTextChangedListener implementations for the 6 Edit Texts may need to be unique in how they handle textChanged events. You will need to pass in the objects in which they are responsible for changing in their constructors.
ie

```
EditText et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
EditText et2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
et1.setOnTextChangedListener(new TextChangedListener(et2){

 //global var       
     EditText nextEditText;


    public TextChangedListener(EditText editText){
      super();
      nextEditText = editText;
    }     

  public void onTextChanged(){

    this.alert();
  }

  public void alert(){
    //modify data here and update self if necessary.

    //then alert the next boxes on text changed method.
    nextEditText = editText.getListener().alert();
  }


});
```